# Is it possible to cluster by Ingestion Time a BQ table partitioned by Ingestion Time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We currently use a BQ table partitioned by day on a column `date1` and clustered by the same date column `date1`. This enables us to optimize our costs. However, we would like to use the tables partitioned by ingestion time instead but I haven't found if it was possible to also cluster by _PARTITIONTIME.

Does anyone know if we can do such thing in BigQuery ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

From [a recent release, BigQuery clustering is independent of the partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#June_09_2020). Therefore, there is no limitation with (or without) ingestion time partitioning. I did a test and it worked great

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but what I want is to cluster by _PARTITIONTIME (which does not really exists) and I haven't found how to do it

Comment: _PARTITIONTIME is a pseudo column that only exist when you partition by Ingestion time. If you don't partition by Ingestion time, it doesn't exist. If you partition, the clustering is useless (because already in partition). The solution here is to set a column when you ingest your data to set this ingestion date manually.

Comment: Hi thanks, that's what we gonna do. However, it is not useless as the clustering still reduces the cost. If you partition by day you are assured of a maximum cost of 1D of data. However, most of the queries use only one hour data and the clustering then helps reducing the cost. It is however not possible to partition by hour as we are limited to 4000 partitions

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, clustering on pseudo-columns is not supported. A workaround would be to use a column for your ingestion time as a partition and a cluster key.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_a_time-unit_column-partitioned_table

[query results screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmWdb.png)